# Como consumir um serviço autenticado com OAuth2 no NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth2, oauth

Estou tentando implementar a autenticação OAuth2 numa aplicação REST NodeJS com Express + Passport. Essa minha aplicação REST NodeJS será uma API para um serviço a ser consumido por um aplicativo mobile, que estou desenvolvendo para Android.

No OAuth2 tem um ClientID e um ClientSecret, que em APIs/serviços com Facebook, Google, etc, você entra num "painel de controle" dos caras e cria esses parâmetros de ClientID e ClientSecret para inserir no aplicativo mobile (por exemplo) que irá acessar a API/serviço.

**PERGUNTA 1**: 
Na minha aplicação REST, que será acessada usando autenticação OAuth2, como faço para criar o ClientID e ClientSecret que serão inseridos no meu app Android?

**PERGUNTA 2**: Esses parâmetros ClientID e ClientSecret serão sempre os mesmos em todos os dispositivos Android executando meu app ao acessar esse serviço/API REST ou cada dispositivo tem que ter o seu ClientID e ClientSecret?

Answer (score -1):

Pode criar o ClientID e o ClientSecret no painel de controle. Depois tem que redirecionar o utilizador para um URL para obter um authorization code.

Mais informação: [Google Cloud - Authenticate Users](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users)